# f: Z -> Z_n in R and haskell

Tags: r, haskell

Is there a straight-forward way to translate the following R code into haskell?

For any function f:Z -> Z_n (Z for the set of integers, Z_n for the set {0, 1, 2, ..., (n-1)}, f(i) = j if and only if f(i) is congruent with j mod n, i.e. f(i) has the same remainder as j when divided by n.

The following R code tries to make an n by n matrix M, so that when f(i) = j, 
M(i,j) = 1, otherwise M(i,j) = 0.

```
# visualize functions in Z_n
zn_func = function(n, f) {
    n1 = n - 1
    # make a single column matrix with elements {f(0), f(1), f(2), ... f(n-1)}
    x = matrix(f(0:n1), ncol = 1)
    # repeat this column n times
    x = x[, rep(1, n)]
    # set row and col names
    rownames(x) = colnames(x) = 0:n1
    # get f(x) mod n
    y = x %% n
    # make a single row matrix with elements {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1}
    rs = matrix(0:n1, nrow = 1)
    # repeat that row n times
    rs = rs[rep(1, n), ]
    rownames(rs) = colnames(rs) = 0:n1
    # determine if y[i, j] == rs[i, j]
    # z is a matrix of type bool
    z = y == rs
    # z + 0 converts z into a matrix of type integer
    # FALSE -> 0, TRUE -> 1
    z=z+0
    list(x=x, y=y, z=z)
}
f = function(x) x^2
zn_func(7, f)
```

See it in action:

```
> zn_func(7, f)
$x
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
3  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
4 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
5 25 25 25 25 25 25 25
6 36 36 36 36 36 36 36

$y
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$z
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
6 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

The `$z` part is what we are after. In this case, it says that in Z_7, under f(x) = x^2, f(6) = 1, f(4) = f(3) = 2, f(2) = 4, etc.

I have tried the hmatrix library, but it won't even allow a matrix of integers. It's doable with list of lists, but I prefer to use an existing library made ready for matrix operations.

Comment: `let m = 7 in map(\i ->  (map (\ j -> (mod (i^2) m == j)) [0..m-1]))[0..m-1]`

Comment: Snarky answer: ```type Matrix i a = i -> i -> a; zn_func :: Num a => a -> (i -> a) -> Matrix i Bool; zn_func n f = \row col -> ((==) `on` (`mod` n)) row (f col)``` But to give a real answer, you should write some code of your own and tell us what's bad about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did after some discussion on #haskell irc channel:

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
znFunc n f = res where
  res_raw = [[if f i `rem` n == j then 1 else 0 | j <- [0 .. (n-1)]] | i <- [0 .. (n-1)]]
  res = fromRows $ map fromList res_raw
```

Testing:

```
> znFunc 7 (^2)
(7><7)
 [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
```

Results are the same as in R. The printing is not as pretty as in R, but at this point i don't know how to improve on it.